# draw & zoom in the same canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Dear Stackoverflow users,

i'm working on a web agenda which works like a giant canvas on which people can draw (the kind of agenda you could find in a bar for instance)

i'm new to javascript, but i managed tinker with bits of code to

- zoom in and out a canvas

  draw in a canvas

i was trying to use the jquery library (zoomooz) which enables you to zoom in a div by clicking on it, but it messes up the drawing part of my code. (basically what you're drawing and the mouse pointer get unsynchronized)

then i found another piece of code to zoom in a canvas directly (without the jquery library).. so i tried to merge the drawing script with that script, but it doesn't work, as you could expect from such a collage.

mabye someone could suggest either a way to fix my problem with the jquery library or how to use a canvas with both the drawing and the zooming script. Or maybe documentation to improve my skills with the javascript canvas..
i hope i'm clear enough.
once this problem is solved i'll start thinking about the backend part of the project...

```css
div {
 border:1px solid black;
 width:1000px;
 height:152px;
 margin: none;
 font-size: 0px;

}


div div {
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background: #aaa;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

div div div {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

canvas{ position: absolute; z-index: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hierarchy test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script>

</head>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
    y = 2;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }

    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "green":
            x = "green";
            break;
            case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
            case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
            case "yellow":
            x = "yellow";
            break;
            case "orange":
            x = "orange";
            break;
            case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
            case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.top = "10px";
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.left = "5px";
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.zIndex = "-1";

    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<body class="container" onload="init()">

    <canvas id="can" width="1000" height="300" style="position:absolute;top:5;left:5;border:2px solid;"></canvas>

    <div id="w1" class="week">
        <div id="d1" class="day">
            <div id="bd1" class="bouton"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="d2" class="day">
            <div id="bd2" class="bouton"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="d3" class="day">
            <div id="bd3" class="bouton"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#bd1").click(function(evt) {
                $("#d1").zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });
            $("#bd2").click(function(evt) {
                $("#d2").zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });
            $("#bd3").click(function(evt) {
                $("#d3").zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Sam! I suggest the Mozilla Developer Network, which has a lot of great information on the `canvas` api.

My guess is that your coordinates are getting out of sync. You'll need to get coordinates relative to the element you're drawing in and then scale them by the amount of zoom.

Comment: thanks for the warm welcome! i'm currently reading doc and trying to understand the script..